# How to give staff access to newly created User In Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I am new to Djnago and Python.
I created middleware class in Djnago with the name StaffAccessMiddleware
I used social_django app to create user from Gmail and i want to implement
`is_staff = True` and assign at least one group only if users login in DJango firstTime .

My question is how to access user in middleware and check only first time user will enter in this code in that case i need to assign `is_staff = True` and assign group once user is created.

I tried to create middle ware class like below.

```
class StaffAccessMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
                user = request.user
        if groups:
            groups[0].name
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `pipeline`, something like this:

1. Add a custom pipeline to update user as `is_staff=True`
2. In that pipeline check for `is_new` parameter and update user only when `is_new` is `True`. Social-auth sends `is_new=True` when user is logging in for first time i.e. when user is created.
3. Add your custom pipeline in `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` settings.
4. Then you can restrict some views to staff users only by specifying `permission_required` settings.

Your final pipeline may look something like this:

```
def make_new_user_as_staff(backend, user, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'gmail' and is_new:
        user.is_staff = False
        user.save()
```

In `settings.py` (or settings file)

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    #other pipelines goes here
    "<full-path-to-make_new_user_as_staff-pipeline>",
    #some other pipelines goes here
)
```

Reference : https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html

Let me know if I have misunderstood your query/this doesn't resolve your issue